# Add class to 1st and 3rd div - then reset count and start again

Tags: jquery, addclass

I'm hoping someone can help.

I have a page made up of 3 divs (showing archived newsletters), then a clearBoth - then another row of 3 divs etc.

Basically what i want to do - rather than manually assigning classes to the 1st and 3rd div every time i update the page with a new newsletter (most recent first) - is top assign classes through jQuery. However, i want the count to reset itself after the clearBoth so as to ensure that the classes are assigned to the correct divs.

I understand that jQuery is 0 based, so I would need a class called 'firstPanel' assigned to the 0 div (appears as 1st), and then a class of 'floatRight' assigned to the 2nd (which appears as the 3rd).

Currently I have this function...

```
$(function(){
$('.newsletterPanel:nth-child(1n)').addClass('firstPanel');
$('.newsletterPanel:nth-child(2n)').removeClass('firstPanel');
$('.newsletterPanel:nth-child(3n)').addClass('floatRight');
});
```

Which is generating the following HTML...

```
<div class="newsletterPanel"><a class="panelLink" href="/emailnewsletters/2011-06-29/online.html" target="_blank">View newsletter </a>
          <div class="newsletterInfo">
            <p>Broadcasted on 29/06/2011</p>
            <p class="genericLinkButton"><a href="/emailnewsletters/2011-06-29/online.html" target="_blank" rel="group">View June's newsletter <span class="smallArrow">&gt;</span></a></p>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsletterPanel firstPanel"><a class="panelLink" href="/emailnewsletters/2011-05-25/online.html" target="_blank">View newsletter </a>
          <div class="newsletterInfo">
            <p>Broadcasted on 25/05/2011</p>
            <p class="genericLinkButton"><a href="/emailnewsletters/2011-05-25/online.html" target="_blank" rel="group">View May's newsletter <span class="smallArrow">&gt;</span></a></p>
          </div>

        </div><div class="clearBoth"></div>
        <div class="newsletterPanel floatRight"><a class="panelLink" href="/emailnewsletters/2011-04-27/online.html" target="_blank">View newsletter </a>
          <div class="newsletterInfo">
            <p>Broadcasted on 27/04/2011</p>
            <p class="genericLinkButton"><a href="/emailnewsletters/2011-04-27/online.html" target="_blank" rel="group">View April's newsletter <span class="smallArrow">&gt;</span></a></p>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="newsletterPanel firstPanel"><a class="panelLink" href="/emailnewsletters/2011-03-09/online.html" target="_blank">View newsletter </a>
          <div class="newsletterInfo">
            <p>Broadcasted on 09/03/2011</p>
            <p class="genericLinkButton"><a href="/emailnewsletters/2011-03-09/online.html" target="_blank" rel="group">View March's newsletter <span class="smallArrow">&gt;</span></a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsletterPanel"><a class="panelLink" href="/emailnewsletters/2011-01-27/online.html" target="_blank">View newsletter </a>

          <div class="newsletterInfo">
            <p>Broadcasted on 27/01/2011</p>
            <p class="genericLinkButton"><a href="/emailnewsletters/2011-01-27/online.html" target="_blank" rel="group">View January's newsletter <span class="smallArrow">&gt;</span></a></p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

Now the problem is the classes are not being applied to the right divs.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function(){
   var $this, count = 0, className;
   $('div.newsletterPanel').each(function(i){

       $this = $(this);
       if($this.next().is("div.clearBoth")){
          count = 0;
          $this.addClass("floatRight");
       }
       else{
        if(count == 0)
          $this.addClass("firstPanel");
        else if(count == 1)
          $this.removeClass("firstPanel");

        count++;
       }


   });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, that will save me a lot of manual editing!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand why you wouldn't just want to assign a class to the 1st and 3rd via your server-side language of choice (I'm assuming that this data is being populated from a datasource via a loop server side?) You could then apply your styles through just CSS. (eg. create your elements with the classes "odd" or "even" and have a corresponding style)

This would have a few benefits:

1. Code cleanliness: This would separate client-side presentation code from server-side content code.
2. Maintainability: It's much easier to just change your CSS style rather than have to refactor your JS should you want to change it (for example, what if you should want to add more divs down the road?)
3. [Keep it simple!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Do you need to apply the classes to the child elements as part of a work-around?

Comment: Hi. The HTML is not populated via a datasource, the page is static. I presently have the classes hardcoded in the HTML however when a newsletter is archived, it's added to the front of the archive - meaning that I then have to go through the rest of the divs and change the classes manually in order to have them still fit 3 to a row. For example... July should have a class of firstPanel, June doesn't have an extra class and May has a class of rightPanel. When August is added, i will need to manually go through and change July's and May's classes as they shift onto new rows/new positions.

Comment: I just thought that if i started with all the panels having the class 'newsletterPanel' (which applied the background image etc - and then could use jQuery to apply the positioning classes, that would save me a lot of hassle. Obviously the easiest solution would be to have them display oldest first, and then no classes would need to be changed on the existing divs as I'd be adding to the end - but ideally i wanted them displaying most recent first. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: is there ever going to be a server in this picture? Or is this more of a single page application in JS?

Answer (score 0):

Use these selectors:

```
newsletterPanel:nth-child(3n+1)
newsletterPanel:nth-child(3n+2)
newsletterPanel:nth-child(3n+3)
```

if you need repeatable groups of 3 elements each.